# How to set up Gcloud Flex Environment custom container pylibmc

Tags: python, django, gcloud

I am trying to set up memcached for my application.
Locally it works just fine.

Now time to deploy to a real server, I am using Google cloud app engine flex environment.

It's a custom runtime.
I am able to install my app just fine, but when it comes time to running, I get a 500 for views that I use Memcached.

My first thinking is because of the caches settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
  }
```

I am thinking it has something to do with this location setting.
Being that this '127.0.0.1:11211' works for a local environment, how do I setup a location for gcloud custom runtime flex environment?

If that's not why I am getting the 500, what could be the better setup.
Here is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8

EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install  --reinstall -y \
  binutils \
  libproj-dev \
  libmemcached11 \
  libmemcachedutil2 \
  libmemcached-dev \
  libz-dev

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

ADD . .

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 main:app --timeout 0 --preload
```

and app.yaml file:

```
runtime: custom

# the PROJECT-DIRECTORY is the one with settings.py and wsgi.py
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 app.wsgi
#entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app.wsgi 
env: flex # for Google Cloud Flexible App Engine

# any environment variables you want to pass to your application.
# accessible through os.environ['VARIABLE_NAME']
env_variables:
  DEBUG: 'False' # always False for deployment
  ....
  STATIC_URL: 'https://storage.googleapis.cd...' you sync static files to
  

beta_settings:
# from command >> gcloud sql instances describe DATABASE-NAME <<
  cloud_sql_instances: apppp-instance

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 4

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the error it's given  you? Please check the Logs from your Google Cloud Platform Logging Console for your App Engine app and share the errors.

Comment: @NibrassH unfortunately, the logs have no errors. which is quite frustrating why no logs and not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [App Engine Flexible Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#memcache), The Memcache service is not available in the App Engine flexible environment. To cache application data, you can use [Memorystore for Redis](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-memorystore). You can follow the next Documentation in order to connect to your [Redis instance from an App Engine flexible environment application](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex#python)

Also please bear in mind that According to the Official Documentation of the App Engine Flexible environment [Python 3.8 is still not supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#base).
However now [App Engine Standard does support Python 3.8](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart).

Comment: How is this related to my question? Memcached I asked about not gdal

Comment: I think you are getting 500 errors because you are trying to use Python 3.8 which still for Flexible environment is not supported. So the Dockerfile above is an example of how to install Python 3.8,  you can adjust the above Dockerfile depending on you needs and re-check if it works that way.

Comment: Thank you. Google is actually very confusing at times. In the console there is Memcached but now I am seeing somewhere that it doesn't support Memcached.. So weird.